# Scoring function for RidgeClassifierCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to implement a custom scoring function for RidgeClassifierCV in scikit-learn.  This involves passing a custom scoring function as the `score_func` when initializing the `RidgeClassifierCV` object.  I expected the score_func to take in categorical values as input for `y_true` and `y_pred`.  Instead, however, floating point values are passed in as `y_true` and `y_pred`.  The size of the y vectors is equal to the number of classes times the number of training examples, rather than simply having a y vector with length equivalent to the number of training examples.

Can I somehow force categorical predictions to be passed into the custom scoring function, or do I have to deal with the raw weights?  If I do have to deal directly with the raw weights, is the index of the maximum value in a slice of the vector of outputs equivalent to the predicted class?

Comment: This is another [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3302) :) - found yesterday as a direct consequence to the other one you uncovered.

Comment: As a hacky workaround to this, since you are using your own score function, I propose that you threshold the continuous values at 0. Positive values become your first class label and negative ones the second. (Or are you using more than 2 labels?)

Comment: And again, thanks for reporting!

Comment: This question still shows up as unanswered. Can we close this without marking it as "does not belong here"?

Comment: Agreed... @eickenberg would you mind posting a bug update as an "answer" so that this comes off the top of the unanswered #python list?

Comment: @emunsing I added an answer

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3302) that has been fixed.